# Python timed input

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a python game-bot where a user needs to send in an input within a certain amount of time.

My current implementation of this is to spawn a new thread that sleeps for that amount of time, then checks if an input has been sent. A nonce is added as the time could run out after another thread starts which would cause the `if chatid in user_threads` part to evaluate to true. Should I use this method or is there a better solution to having a timed input (in the sense less likely to fail due to like race conditions).

I've also tried using `multiprocessing.Process` but sharing variables to the other process seems to be a lot more cumbersome.

```
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint

user_threads = {}

def timeout(t,r):
    while time()-t<5:
        sleep(5-time()+t)
    if chatid in user_threads:
        if user_threads[chatid][3] != r:
            return
        del user_threads[chatid]
        print("Too slow")

def recvans(ans,inp):
    if ans==inp:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")

def starttimer(chatid):
    r = randint(0,1<<128)
    user_threads[chatid] = [None,None,None,r]
    user_threads[chatid][2] = ["a"]
    P = Thread(target = timeout, args = (time(),r))
    user_threads[chatid][0] = P
    user_threads[chatid][1] = recvans
    P.start()

while True: # simulating user input from different users (here chatid=1)
    inp = input()
    chatid = 1
    if chatid in user_threads:
        t, func, args, _ = user_threads[chatid]
        if t == None:
            print("Please wait")
            continue
        del user_threads[chatid]
        args += [inp]
        func(*args)
        continue
    if inp == "Start":
        starttimer(chatid)
        continue
    if inp == "Quit":
        break
    print("Unknown msg")
```

Comment: Usually is is done via [select.select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#module-select)

Answer (score 1):

What @vnp said. Fundamentally,

- `input` uses `stdin`;
- `stdin` can be interpreted as a file handle so long as you're not in Windows;
- `select` can wait for data availability on such handles.

There's a lot of internet help on this topic, including https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471853/313768 ; to quote the solution there:

> ```
> import sys 
> from select import select
>
> timeout = 10 
> print "Enter something:", 
> rlist, _, _ = select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout) 
> if rlist:
>     s = sys.stdin.readline()
>     print s 
> else:
>     print "No input. Moving on..."
> ```

Comment: ahh ic this looks way cleaner
for my case since I'm using this in context of a game which receives http(s) requests is there a similar way to do this?